# How to format a URL to get a file from Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, get

I am having some trouble figuring out how to access a file from Amazon S3. Lets say that the bucket that the file lives in is `BUCKET_NAME`, the file is `FILE_NAME`, etc. I have tried the following two URLs:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME/
?Expires=EXPIRATION
&Signature=SIGNATURE
&SignatureVersion=2
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1
&AWSAccessKeyId=KEYID
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
```

I have also tried:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/
?Key=FILE_NAME
&Expires=EXPIRATION
&Signature=SIGNATURE
&SignatureVersion=2
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1
&AWSAccessKeyId=KEYID
```

but this returns a webpage with a list of all of the files in the given bucket (including `FILE_NAME`), instead of the specific file I want. I have also tried throwing in `Action=GetObject` into the URL as well but that doesn't seem to change anything.

It would be helpful to find out which (if any) is the proper method and what I am doing wrong. I have been digging through Amazon's documentation for a while now but I can't seem to sort it out.

Comment: for programmers looking. thought i would add this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Answer (score 74):

Its actually formulated more like:

```
https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>
```

See [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTBucketGET.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have also tried the way that you mentioned, but with the same results.

Comment: @user1018928 Is it a versioned bucket? Also to consider is if the key is deleted.

Answer (score 36):

Documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAPI.html), and I'll use the Frankfurt region as an example.

## There are 2 different URL styles:

- Virtual host style: https://BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/FILE
- Path style: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/FILE

But this url does not work:

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/FILE

The message is explicit: `The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.`

I may be talking about another problem because I'm not getting `NoSuchKey` error but I suspect the error message has been made clearer over time.

Comment: Path style URLs are deprecated. AWS will drop support for them at some point in the future. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps not what the OP was after, but for those searching the URL to simply access a readable object on S3 is more like:

`https://<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/<key>`

Where `<region>` is something like `s3-ap-southeast-2`.

Click on the item in the S3 GUI to get the link for your bucket.

Comment: Putting the bucket name in the path instead of the domain is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

As @stevebot said, do this:

`https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>`

The one important thing I would like to add is that you either have to make your bucket objects all publicly accessible OR you can add a custom policy to your bucket policy. That custom policy could allow traffic from your network IP range or a different credential.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you're in a different AWS partition, such as US GovCloud or China then you'll have a slightly different URL pattern.

`https://<bucket-name>.s3-<region-name>.amazonaws.com/<key>` works for GovCloud.

China is something like `https://<bucket-name>.s3-<region-name>.amazonaws.com.cn/<key>`.

Comment: Only problem I see is the hyphen between s3 and region name, I've added an answer very similar to this

Answer (score 1):

The date is 08.03.23 and the current way to format the url is this:

```
https://<bucket>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/<key>
```

Answer (score 0):

Format of the Url

```
https://${bucketName}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${key}
```

Example of public access URL
https://store-files-in-s3.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/image-Fri+Mar+08+2024+17%3A45%3A07+GMT%2B0530+(India+Standard+Time).png

Key in above example: `image-Fri Mar 08 2024 17:45:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time).png`